# How to access data afer gmail opendid authentication?

Tags: single-sign-on

I have successfully completed implementing Gmail openid into my website (asp.net),in which once the user make a successful login onto his/her gmail account, he/she is reverted back to my page.But i am not able to figure out how to access the data(data like their first name ,last name and city ) ,once the user comes to my aspx. page.
Plz help

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is oauth, not openid. More information on oauth and how to use google data Apis at http://code.google.com/apis/gdata.